# Print value of an array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with value

```
Array (
    [und] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [value] =>
Drupal Development
PHP
CSS
MySql
Photoshop
Illustrator
InDesign
             [format] =>
             [safe_value] => <li class="drupal">Drupal Development</li> <li class="php">PHP</li> <li class="css">CSS</li> <li class="mysql">MySql</li> <li class="ps">Photoshop</li> <li class="il">Illustrator</li> <li class="in">InDesign</li>
         )
     )
 )
```

the array is `$node->field_spec` How can i get to print the value and safe value? I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$safe_value = $node->field_spec['und'][0]['safe_value']
```

See [`arrays`](http://php.net/arrays)